# Events lists with one or more days length in next 14 days

Tags: sql, date

I have an events list created with php/mysql which displays up and coming events in the next 14 days. The db has 8 fields

```
event_ID,
date_1,
date_2,
eventTitle,
eventDetails,
location,
publish,
updated.
```

I have created a list using this sql statement

```
SELECT gpe.*, gpr.name 
FROM growl_presevents gpe, growl_presrail gpr 
WHERE gpe.location LIKE gpr.railID AND (date_1 >= '$today' AND date_1 <= '$week') 
AND gpe.publish = 'y' 
ORDER BY date_1 ASC
```

The arrays are filled by these statements

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');                     /// Todays date

$week = date('Y-m-d', time() + (86400*14)); /// Todays date + 14 days
```

The list is fine, but I need a tweak so that an event is displayed if it lasts for more than one day, and the date_1 is outside the 14 day period.

e.g. (just example data not actual)

if today is 2012-02-01

```
date_1      date_2      location   Title         details

2012-02-07  NULL        Loc001     Show          Stage show

2012-02-13  2012-02-18  Loc002     Open Air      Festival

2012-02-17  NULL        Loc001     Comedy        Comedy Show
```

Using my SQL query above, the first two dates would show '$today', on the '3rd' all three would be displayed, then on the '8th' the first row would disappear. All OK so far, but this is where I need help. Using this query on the '14th' row 2 would disappear, but the event is on until the 18th, therefore I want it to still display until the 18th.

There is probably an easy way of doing this, but I have not been able to fathom it out, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT gpe.*, gpr.name  
FROM growl_presevents gpe, growl_presrail gpr  
WHERE gpe.location LIKE gpr.railID 
AND (
    (date_1 >= '$today' AND date_1 <= '$week')
    OR (ISNULL(date_2,0) >= '$today' AND ISNULL(date_2,0) <= '$week')
    )  
AND gpe.publish = 'y'  
ORDER BY date_1 ASC
```

So basically do the same check on date_2 as you do on date_1 as an OR. Use ISNULL to provide 0 if a NULL date is found.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have now sorted the list :)